# Adding constraint with HttpGet (...) does not work in ASP.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-routing

I am newbie to ASP.NET core platform. I am working on sample application where I am pooling some daily data from service. My API signature as below -

```
[HttpGet("daily/{state}/{year}/{month}/{day}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Daily([FromRoute] string state, [FromRoute] int year, [FromRoute] int month, [FromRoute] int day)
{
    //...
}
```

My requirement is to restrict `state` parameter to 3 characters and all caps.

So I did this -

```
[HttpGet("daily/{state:regex(A-Z):maxlength(3)}/{year}/{month}/{day}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Daily([FromRoute] string state, [FromRoute] int year, [FromRoute] int month, [FromRoute] int day)
{
    //...
}
```

If I add these constraints on route, I am getting *page not found* error.

It works fine if I put no constraint.

Updated - See following screen-shot from VS2017. I am passing URL like `http://localhost:51208/api/daily/mah/2018/08/13` and still ModelState's IsValid returns true. Why?

[image]

Comment: `It does not work`.What does that mean? What is the expectation compared to what is actually happening? What URL are you calling that *does not work*?

Comment: check up on your regex. I think `regex(A-Z)` would apply to only one character

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is in a more cleaner way is make a model for your get request.

```
  public class DailyModel
    {
        [Required]
        [RegularExpression("^[A-Z]{3}$", ErrorMessage ="State should be length of 3 and all in Upper Case")]
        public string State { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public int Month { get; set; }
        public int Day { get; set; }
    }
```

And apply data annotation to your fields like the above code. And on your controller, you can send the model state invalid message if the request is not valid.

```
  [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class TestController : Controller
    {

        [HttpGet("daily/{state}/{year}/{month}/{day}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Daily([FromRoute] DailyModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

          ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I want to get these parameters from route only.

Comment: @Omkar yes you can do same with FromRoute attribute too. See my updated answer. Just you need to introduce a new model as on my answer.

Comment: @Omkar you are not using model as I suggested.  You should have parameter of model . You don't want to use model? It is more best practice to use that way.

Comment: Extremely clean :)

Answer (score 2):

Not found is because the URL being called most likely does not match the regex constraint.

Consider checking your regular expression.

Simple example

```
^[A-Z]{1,3}$
```

> Matches a single character in the range: [A-Z] between 1 and 3 times.

That means it will match from `A` to `ZZZ`

If the length must be exactly 3 characters then remove the range

```
^[A-Z]{3}$
```

Which will match `AAA` to `ZZZ`

So update the constraint accordingly.

```
[HttpGet("daily/{state:regex(^[[A-Z]]{{3}}$)}/{year:int}/{month:int}/{day:int}")]
```

> Note that Regular expression tokens must be escaped. For example, `\`,`{`,`}`,`[`,`]` characters need to be escaped by doubling them to escape the Routing parameter delimiter characters.

Reference [Routing in ASP.NET Core: Regular expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2#regular-expressions) about escaping the regular expression.

For the desired match

```
GET {host}/daily/ABC/2019/01/20
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this matches to - GET {host}/daily/abc/2019/01/20 and GET {host}/daily/aBC/2019/01/20. My intention is to get 404 in these cases.

Comment: Yes. You are right. The regular expression is showing expected result if tried in regex editor but this fail if put into URL.

Comment: If the constraint is not working as expected then I would consider validating it yourself and updating model state

Comment: @Omkar have a look at this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2#implementing-iactionconstraint